# Is it haram to pray in the complete opposite direction?

Tags: halal-haram, salat, qiblah

Let's say you are praying, and someone stands right behind you praying 180 degrees away from the direction your praying in. Wouldn't it be the exact same thing considering the fact that the earth is round and you both are praying in the same direction?

Comment: I guess there may be only two places on Earth where two people can pray like that: one is inside the Ka'aba itself, and the other on its diametrically opposite side of the globe.

Answer (score 5):

**`So from wherever you go out [for prayer] turn your face toward al- Masjid al-Haram, and indeed, it is the truth from your Lord. And Allah is not unaware of what you do. Quran 2:149`**

So if you are standing near masjid al haram if you turn 180 degree opposite, you will not be facing your "face" towards masjid al haram. So I assume we have to stand in the shortest direction towards masjid al haram. Technically standing 180 degree will be ok in place where mecca is same distance both ways but still for maintaining uniformity one direction need to be decided by Muslims there.

But if you have real difficulty in facing the right direction or is unable to find the right direction, it is not haraam (forbidden) to pray in different direction.

Comment: +1, To add to your answer, when it is said that you turn in some direction it means the shortest possible distance and if possible see it. It is common sense and such questions are perhaps from shaytan, he just wants to tangle our brain!.

Comment: The place on Earth from where Kaaba is the same distance in both directions is a remote point somewhere in South Pacific Ocean. This is called [antipod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antipodes). I thought to bring it up as you mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

If done unintentionally, then it is absolutely ok because wherever you face, everything belongs to and glorifies Allaah SWT.

If you are talking about intentionally praying towards the opposite side then it is totally wrong and Your faith might be jeopardised for doing this so never take such a risk EVER!.

Answer (score -1):

Definitely it won't be true if u prayer on the opposite direction of Qiblah
And in fact the right direction is only one and praying on other directions is invalid, otherwise Allah would tell us to pray on each direction that we like.